# PHP array push data use id as key name

Tags: php

Trying to use array push and make the array key equal to the product ID so that it can be later removed. I've tried array_fill_keys that hasn't worked.

PHP code is:

```
$key = $_POST['product'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['cart_items']); $i++) { 
    $key_s = array_search($key, $_SESSION['cart_items'][$i]);
    echo $key_s;

    if ($_SESSION['cart_items'][$i][$key_s] == $key) 
    {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$i]); 
        echo "found it";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not found";
    }
}
var_dump($_SESSION['cart_items']);
```

output is:

```
not foundnot foundarray(2) {
    [3]=>
        array(3) {
            ["item_id"] => string(4) "1131"
            ["item_name"] => string(36) "10 Ways A Condom Can’t Protect You"
            ["item_qty"] => string(2) "12"
        }
    [4]=>
        array(3) {
            ["item_id"] => string(4) "1131"
            ["item_name"] => string(36) "10 Ways A Condom Can’t Protect You"
            ["item_qty"] => string(2) "12"
    }
}
0
```

Comment: what error you are getting and what will be the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
    $search = 'red';
    foreach($array as $key => $item){
        if($item == $search){
            unset ($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but are you over-complicating a bit?

```
    $key = $_POST['product'];

    for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['cart_items']);$i++){ 

        if ($_SESSION['cart_items'][$i]['item_id'] == $key) {
           unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$i]); 
           echo "found it";
        }
        else {
           echo "not found";
        }
    }
    var_dump($_SESSION['cart_items']);
```

Just leave out the `$key_s` and `array_search` and you should be good. `$_POST['product']` should contain an `item_id`, right?

**EDIT**

If the array keys are not in order, the above won't work. You could just use `foreach` instead.

Like:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_times'] as $cart_key => $id) {
    if ($id == $key) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$cart_key]);
        echo "found it";
    }
    else {
        echo "not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does - will test it after lunch!

Comment: This will work if the array is in order, however the for check won't work if the array keys are not in order ( 3,4,2 ). how can this be solved?